# How to create specific language package for an item?

Tags: package-designer

We have a multilingual site and want to create a Sitecore package of items, but only include one specific language only (for example `de-de` (German language)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you select `Items dynamically` source option, you can use `Language filter`:

[image]

Preview clearly shows that only `de` version is added to the package:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On Sitecore Package Designer choose 'Items dynamically' option .
 On second step you can choose Language filter option where you can specify particular language for items.

[image]

Comment: If you install a package with only one language version, won't the other language versions of your items in the target environment be deleted when you install the package?